# Authorizing Access with JWT tokens in asp.net mvc website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jwt

I would like to use jwt tokens for authorization in my ASP.NET MVC website. I have already created an api that generates the jwt token from this tutorial :
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-web-api-2-creating-and-validating-jwt-json-web-token/

Now I have added the following nuget packages in my asp.net mvc website :

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.5.0 
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt 4.0.1
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin 5.2.3
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 4.0.1
```

And I have also created a startup file and inserted the following code:

```
   app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(  
                   new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions  
                   {  
                       AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,  
                       TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()  
                       {  
                           ValidateIssuer = true,  
                           ValidateAudience = true,  
                           ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,  
                           ValidIssuer = "example.com", //some string, normally web url,  
                           ValidAudience = "example.com",  
                           IssuerSigningKey = new 

    SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my_secret_key_12345"))  

                       }  
                   });
```

I am then using postman to create a jwt token and challenge the website for authorization.
The generate token method is the following. (literally like the tutorial):

```
    public Object GetToken()    
    {    
        string key = "my_secret_key_12345";
        var issuer = "example.com";  //normally this will be your site URL    
      
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));    
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);    
      
        //Create a List of Claims, Keep claims name short    
        var permClaims = new List<Claim>();    
        permClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));    
        permClaims.Add(new Claim("valid", "1"));    
        permClaims.Add(new Claim("userid", "1"));    
        permClaims.Add(new Claim("name", "bilal"));    
      
        //Create Security Token object by giving required parameters    
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, //Issure    
                        issuer,  //Audience    
                        permClaims,    
                        expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),    
                        signingCredentials: credentials);    
        var jwt_token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);    
        return new { data = jwt_token };    
    }
```

I have created the following method to challenge the authorization:

```
[Authorize]
     public string checkbystring()
        {
            return "worked";
        }
```

But when I test it in postman, the following error keeps popping up:
IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 401.0 - Unauthorized

Any suggestions to make this work would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem in ASP NET MVC, my token was generated, but when I used it I got the 401 error.
I needed to create an ASP NET MVC application, which used JWT token, but not Core.
The solution in my case was to include a library that was missing:
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb

```html
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt;
using Owin;
using System.Text;


[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebAPI.Startup))]
namespace WebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly string SecuretyKey = "KEY--$%TESTE&##&#";

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
               new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
               {
                   AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                   TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                   {
                       ValidAudience = "Teste.com",
                       ValidIssuer = "Teste.com",
                       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                           Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecuretyKey)),
                       ValidateLifetime = true,
                       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
                   }
               });
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to it, the image of the other necessary packages follows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXrZf.png)